# Why is my all? function not working? What's wrong with my syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I originally wrote a method to take a word and find out if its vowels were in alphabetical order. I did it by using the code below:

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end
```

However, I decided to try to change it by using an all? method. I tried to do so with the following code:

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a","e", "i", "o", "u"]
  splitted_word = word.split("")
  vowels_in_word = []
  vowels_in_word = splitted_word.select {|word| vowels.include?(word)}

  vowels_in_word.all? {|x| vowels_in_word[x]<= vowels_in_word[x+1]}


end


ordered_vowel_word?("word")
```

Anyone have any ideas why it isnt working? I would have expected this to work.
Also, if anyone has a better solution please feel free to post. Thanks!

Examples are:

```
it "does not return a word that is not in order" do
  ordered_vowel_words("complicated").should == ""
end

it "handle double vowels" do
  ordered_vowel_words("afoot").should == "afoot"
end

it "handles a word with a single vowel" do
  ordered_vowel_words("ham").should == "ham"
end

it "handles a word with a single letter" do
  ordered_vowel_words("o").should == "o"
end

it "ignores the letter y" do
  ordered_vowel_words("tamely").should == "tamely"
end
```

Comment: What errors does it return?

Comment: (eval):631: (eval):631:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
 from (eval):631:in `ordered_vowel_word?'
 from (eval):636:in `all?'
 from (eval):631:in `each'
 from (eval):631:in `all?'
 from (eval):631:in `ordered_vowel_word?'
 from (eval):636

Comment: `x` is a string, as you get it from `splitted_word`.

Comment: It would work with the last line being `words_in_word.sort == vowels_in_word`.

Comment: When your code is giving you errors, you should edit them into your question, and point out which lines of code they refer to. It helps nobody that the error occured at line 636 of your REPL session, make a proper script with the test case.

Comment: do you mean that I can't compare strings with the All? function?? because "a" < "b" == true

Comment: Oh sorry for the wording, you are trying to use your vowels as array indices.

Comment: the original has a bug too `vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]` when `i == vowels_arr.length` will try to compare the entry at `i` to nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def ordered?(word)
  vowels = %w(a e i o u)
  check = word.each_char.select { |x| vowels.include?(x) }
  # Another option thanks to @Michael Papile
  # check = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  puts check.sort == check
end

ordered?("afoot")
ordered?("outaorder")
```

Output is:

```
true
false
```

In your original example, you use the array values (String) as array indices which should be Integers when the `all?` method fires.

Comment: That is nice.  You can probably shorten it by using scan on the check line.  `check = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)`

Comment: @MichaelPapile That's a good point. I mostly just went off of what the user posted. But I'll add that as another option.

Answer (score 2):

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
    vowels = ["a","e", "i", "o", "u"]
    splitted_word = word.split("")
    vowels_in_word = []
    vowels_in_word = splitted_word.select {|word| vowels.include?(word)}
    p vowels_in_word #=> ["o"]
    vowels_in_word.all? {|x| vowels_in_word[x]<= vowels_in_word[x+1]}
end

p ordered_vowel_word?("word")
#=> `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

`vowels_in_word` contains only 'o', and inside the `vowels_in_word.all? {|x| vowels_in_word[x]<= vowels_in_word[x+1]}` the expression `vowels_in_word[x]` means `vowels_in_word["o"]`, which in-turn throws error as index can never be `string`.

Comment: are you debugging using pry? or some ide?

Comment: I am using SublimeText2 as well. How do you run code and/or debug? Right now, I am stuck using irb and repl.it/languages/Ruby  . I am wondering if there is a better way